# Freeform v 5.0.6.1 Render

Tags: craft4, plugin-freeform, freeform

I'm using `"craftcms/cms": "4.7.1"`, My form does not render since I updated to the new most recent version of freeform `"solspace/craft-freeform": "5.0.6.1"`, is there another way to render? this is part of my code:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form("contactForm") %}
    {{ form.renderTag }}
    <div>
      {% for field in form.layout.fields %}
        <fieldset>
          {{ field.render(
            {
              class: field.type != "submit" ? "freeform-input" : "freeform-submit button",
              labelClass: "freeform-label"
            }
          ) }}
        </fieldset>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {{ form.renderClosingTag }}
```